# Trigger a Alert From server side Asp.net MVC Using signal R

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult UpdateMyData(User model)
    {
        _service.add(model);
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    _Data.ProcessBigTask();

                });
    return new JsonResult { Data = "Success") };
    }
```

After complete this Task `( _Data.ProcessBigTask();)` i need a automatic alert on browser

Answer (score 0):

Create new function on client side and call it.

You can create and invoke client function like this.

**Client Side function**

```
var chat = $.connection.myHub;

chat.client.getUpdateStatus = function (msg) {
      alert(msg);
};
```

**HUB**

```
public ActionResult UpdateMyData(User model)
{
    Clients.All.getUpdateStatus ("Status :" + msg);
}
```

Comment: Actually Am beginner in Signal R so i don't get .

Comment: The idea is; you need to create client side function which you can call using Signalr's hub. see this tutorial if you're getting confuse http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5

and check addNewMessageToPage(name, message) function how it's called in that given link.